# Why am I getting this Mathematica error - "Syntax: Incomplete expression more input is needed"

Tags: syntax-error, wolfram-mathematica

I'm running this on Wolfram cloud. Here's the code

```
   ClearAll[s,l,L,L1,M1,Mt,m,M,vym,vxm,wp,J,Meff,theta,omega]
   Rr = {{Cos[theta],-Sin[theta],0},{Sin[theta],Cos[theta],0},{0,0,1}};
   Wm = {0,0,omega};
```

This is obviously part of a larger code, but just this much is enough to create the error. If I remove any line, the error disappears. I can't for the life of me figure out where a syntax error could be in here!

Comment: Hey, the color change is just the posting process. In mathematica, 'Cos' and 'Sin' are in black as they should be.

Comment: It's odd. It works perfectly fine on the link you sent. What could be the trouble in my notebook, then? I've tried quitting kernel/restarting session and that doesn't help.